# Adding custom model to spree logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, model, spree

I want to add custom model/controller to a Spree application in Rails.

Structure what i need:

```
1. Registry

    1.1. Registry1

    1.2. Registry2
```

Taxons:

```
 1. Registry  

     1.1. Registry1

     1.2. Registry2

 2. Categories

    2.1. Category1

        2.1.2. Somesubcategory

     2.2. Category2
```

This is the only reference I've got: https://quickleft.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-model-to-your-spree-app/

So what should be the right (rails) method to do this, because I need to linked it to taxons_id later, search registries,etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The best one that worked for me was [spree scaffold](https://github.com/freego/spree_scaffold)

just add the gem

```
gem 'spree_scaffold', github: 'freego/spree_scaffold', branch: '3-0-stable'
```

run `bundle`

```
rails g spree_scaffold:scaffold Registry name:string
```

*this will create a scaffold for you and a section in admin panel as well... so from here you can further modify it*

hope this would have answered your query